# Is there a way to connect to Terminal Services "More Secure" from non-windows machine?

Tags: ubuntu, remote-access, terminal-server

With Windows Vista and newer, when you enable remote desktop for administration, there are options to allow "Old Clients (less secure) [no network level authentication]" and "New clients (more secure) [with network level authentication]".

Is there any way to connect to the "more secure" version from non-microsoft clients? I've tried from the ubuntu client, and it works to connect to XP/2003 but it fails to connect to a Win7 Desktop or 2008R2 server, though I can connect to both of those machines from another Win7 machine.

Comment: Microsoft has documented the NLA and RD Gateway protocols; to my knowledge no OSS has implemented them yet however. I hoping someone knows of something however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way now! The [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/) project has NLA support, but only in their [git repo](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP) right now not in a stable version. They've had NLA support since late January if I remember right. The next stable version should have full support, but until then you'll have to compile your own.

Comment: Looks like it was announced on [Jan 25th](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=AANLkTim3jRhYnYnoshxji9p4H0j-4TwyYFx-WZiuSoYJ@mail.gmail.com&forum_name=freerdp-devel).

Comment: That looks good. Any pointers on how to get it up and running? My installation experience is limited to `sudo apt-get install` ;)

Comment: @NateBross Then this is probably not for you, since there are package dependencies that are hard to troubleshoot if you haven't done this kind of thing before.

Comment: I'm always looking to expand my skillset, some guidance on getting started is all I'm really looking for, once I know the questions to ask I should be able to figure it out.

Comment: @NateBoss That tree has too many branches in it for me to do it justice here. Also, I'm not that familiar with Ubunbutisms so what I generate may not be useful anyway.